# pq: SSL is not enabled on the server Postrsql golang

Tags: postgresql, go, ssl

I want connect Postresql database with golang

Code :

```
  import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/bmizerany/pq"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    )

  func NewPostSql()(*sql.DB,error) { 
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:ellez2004@localhost:5432/app?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil { 
        return nil,err;
    }
    if err := db.Ping();err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err.Error());
    }
    return db,nil;
}
```

But i get error even though ssl = disable:
Error:

pq: SSL is not enabled on the server

How can I fix this??

Comment: Please post error here.

Comment: error pq: SSL is not enabled on the server

Comment: Works for me.  Can you show your imports so we don't have to guess?

Comment: _ "github.com/bmizerany/pq"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"  i also added in top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find problem "github.com/bmizerany/pq" package not workin.Just need
install
"github.com/lib/pq"

```
  import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    )

  func NewPostSql()(*sql.DB,error) { 
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:ellez2004@localhost:5432/app?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil { 
        return nil,err;
    }
    if err := db.Ping();err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err.Error());
    }
    return db,nil;
}
```

Comment: lib/pq is in maintenance mode and recommends [github.com/jackc/pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) as a replacement. See [the end of the readme](https://github.com/lib/pq#status).

Answer (score -3):

```
func NewPostSql() (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://ellez2004@localhost:5432/app?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err.Error())
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

You should not use `postgres` twice.

Comment: The URL format is `postgres://username:password@host:port`. The second postgres was the username.